# Find integers solution of $x^2-4y+y^2-4x+xy(x-4)(y-4)=2021$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Solve in integers the equation:
$(x^2−4y)+(y^2−4x)+xy(x−4)(y−4)=2021$.

Firstly I noticed that the factors of $2021$ are $43$ and $47$. This has something to do with the $4$ throughout the question as $43-47=-4$. This is my first time doing such type of question. Can the answer be like $(0,-43),(0,47),(-43,0),(47,0)$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Expand the products on the left and see what you can factor.

Comment: @Whichman Welcome to Math SE. Due to concerns about unattributed questions with $2021$ in them potentially being from math contests (e.g., see [How likely is it that a question with 2021 is from a current contest?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33425/602049)), in particular current ones, please edit your question text to state where the problem came from.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it may be from a current contest, with the OP asking a related question yesterday at [Find all positive integers n.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4129664/602049) where $2021$ was also involved, but did not respond to where & when the problem came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method:
$x(x-4)+y(y-4)+xy(x-4)(y-4)=2021$
Let $A = x(x-4), B = y(y-4)$, then $A + B + AB = 2021$.
Hence $(1+A)(1+B) = 2022.  \implies   (1+x^2-4x)(1+y^2-4y) = 2022.$

Comment: Please be careful while answering questions involving 2021 in the title/body, it could be from an ongoing contest. Unless the user leaves a comment to the source you should be careful.